# Flutter: Save state of icons when switching flutter local notifications on/off using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, localnotification

I am using the following code to switch flutter local notifications on/off. This code works fine, but the icon state does not get saved when the app is closed and reopen.

I need to get this current selected icon saved using shared preferences plugin, but I could not manage to do that.

Can someone help me to add shared preferences to this code.

This the variable:

```
  var _icon2 = Icons.notifications_off;
```

This is the code of the icons which run the functions between on/off:

```
IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        _icon2,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_icon2 == Icons.notifications_off) {
                            _icon2 = Icons.notifications_active;
                            _repeatNotification2();
                          } else {
                            _icon2 = Icons.notifications_off;
                            _cancelNotification2();
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: Where are you using shared preferences? I don't see it

Comment: I think your only solution is to create with regex (that will save you some times) a Map with the codePoint of those Icons as key and the IconData as value. Then you can just store the codePoint of the selected icon. Then just retrieve it and find the correspond IconData with the Map you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to add shared preferences to the code.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleBooleanScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SimpleBooleanScreenState createState() => SimpleBooleanScreenState();
}

class SimpleBooleanScreenState extends State<SimpleBooleanScreen> {
  IconData _FirstIcon = Icons.notifications_active;
  bool isIconOneActive = true;
  String keyNameOne = "_updateScreenOneState";
  Future<bool> loadDataOne() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getBool(keyNameOne) ?? true;
  }
  Future<bool> saveDataOne() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.setBool(keyNameOne, isIconOneActive);
  }
  setData() async {
    loadDataOne().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        isIconOneActive = value;
        setIcon();
      });
    });
  }
  setIcon() async {
    if (isIconOneActive) {
      _FirstIcon = Icons.notifications_active;
    } else {
      _FirstIcon = Icons.notifications_off;
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    setData();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Notificaation 1',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0)),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        _FirstIcon,
                        size: 40.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (isIconOneActive) {
                            isIconOneActive = false;
                            setIcon();
                            saveDataOne();
                            _cancelNotification1();
                          } else {
                            isIconOneActive = true;
                            setIcon();
                            saveDataOne();
                            _repeatNotification1();
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```